# android:windowTranslucentStatus / fitsSystemWindows Toolbar wrong size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

Trying to create a simple view with a translucent status bar and toolbar and am having trouble getting the toolbar to behave as I expect. The toolbar seems to use the fitsSystemWindows bool property for it's inner items (Title, Overflow Menu) but not for it's actual position.

I can programmatically get the size of the status bar and resize the toolbar by adding the status bar height but my understanding is `fitsSystemWindows=true` should do that.

[image: Lollipop Screenshot]

**Theme**

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="kitkat">true</item>
    </style>
```

**Layout** - Note: I moved the background to the AppBarLayout because ultimately the goal is to have a background image behind the toolbar. It doesn't change the result if the background is defined on the AppBarLayout or the Toolbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Content Here"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Just hoping there is a simple thing I'm missing that makes this work as I understand it should. Adding the fitsSystemWindows attribute moves the title and overflow menu down, but the toolbar cuts off because it has not been moved.

Answer (score 1):

Toolbar layout changed to a height of wrap_content seems to "fix" the problem.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the **fitsSystemWindows** in the toolbar to **false**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```